# why in nested class can not use imported packages?

Tags: java, oop, generics, types, nested-class

I defined this Node in this package:

```
package provided;
public interface Node{
    public Node getNext();
}
```

here I want to use Node, the problem in the nested class "LinkedListIterator", it is not able to see my Node methods :

```
import provided.Node;
class LinkedList {
    private Node head;
    head.getNext(); // there is no error here, the method getNext() is available 
    class LinkedListIterator <Node> implements Iterator<Node> {
        private Node next_node;
            public Node next(){
                return next_node.getNext(); // The method getNext() is 
                                            // undefined for the type Node 
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the entire error? I see a different issue with this code: `LinkedListIterator.next()` delcares it returns `Node`, while it returns `next_node.getNext()` which is an `Integer`.

Comment: The code example is to messy. I think that problem might be that getNext() that return Node i not defined.

Comment: In your `next` signature, `Public` is capped. That's an error right there. First fix that, then move on to the next problem.

Comment: @nabil: Please copy and paste the **exact** code you are using. It seems to have a lot of typos, maybe the declaration of `getNext()` or its usage is a typo in the code?

Comment: I corrected the question, still the same problem, I'm using eclipse when I type next_node. it should shows me the methods but I don't get the interface methods at all, seems in the nested class does not see the defined interface node

Comment: @nabil, you should start with coding uder notepad rather than IDE(Eclipse). You really miss the point here.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, The problem here is not that the Class Node doesn't have the getNext() method , but its because of the Generics Involved, You have declared your Iterator as `class LinkedListIterator <Node> implements Iterator<Node> {` now , when you declare the variable of type Node , compiler takes it to be of the Generic Type defined by Name 'Node' , to solve this , change the declaration of next node as `private provided.Node next_node;` or alternatively , define another name for generic in ,for eg.. Type , t  etc ..

`

```
class LinkedListIterator <Node> implements Iterator<Node> {
    private provided.Node next_node;

        @Override
        public Node next() {
            return next_node.getNext();
        }
```

`

Comment: yes I did that already and it works, but didn't understand why the compiler won't take the my defined node in generics  ?!
would class LinkedListIterator <provided.Node> implements Iterator<provided.Node>  work ?

Comment: @nabil whatever we pass in as Generic Types is just the name, its not the actual class names or types to be returned, may be you would like to read more about Type Erasure  at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html , this would help you understand the problem , write in case you are still not sure of the reason

Answer (score 0):

you've got this in your interface

```
 public Integer getNext();
```

but your anonymous class has this defined

```
Public Node next() {
   return next_node.getNext()
```

which mismatches the return type.  you need to change your interface to something like this

```
 public Node getNext();
```

Comment: Though true, it is not answer - since it will not generate the specified error. [That's why I put it as a comment]. It also mismatches the OP's edit.

Comment: I corrected the question, still the same problem, I'm using eclipse when I type next_node. it should shows me the methods but I don't get the interface methods at all, like in the nested class does not see the defined interface node.